# Automorphisms of subgroup of hamming cube under distance constraint

Tags: co.combinatorics, coding-theory, finite-groups, gr.group-theory, automorphism-groups

Let $S$ be a subset of $\{0,1\}^n$ such that any two elements of $S$ are at least (Hamming) distance 5 apart. I'm looking for an upper bound on the size of the automorphism group of $S$.

There's a trivial upper bound of $2^nn!$ (the number of automorphisms of $\{0,1\}^n$), and an easy lower bound of $2^{n/5}(n/5)!$ (take S to be all elements of the form $xxxxx$, where $x$ is a bitstring of length $n/5$).

Any bound of the form $n!/n^{cn}$ for any $c>0$ would be helpful.

Comment: Such a set would be a 2-error correcting binary code. You might search for constructions and see if some provide good lower bounds.

Comment: Thanks for the comment. Haven't found anything yet that I've gotten to work, but I'll post here if I do.

Comment: You seem to allow translations as well as permutations of coordinates, don't you? Do you treat the automorphism group as a subgroup of the isometries of the entire Hamming space? Or do you treat it as a subgroup of $Sym(S)$? The former is IMHO standard in coding theory (usually translations aren't allowed though). I am asking because the choice $S=\{111110^{n-5},0^n\}$ leads to a very large group with the "standard" interpretation: any permutation of the last $n-5$ coordinates $\times$ any permutation of the first five coordinates $\times$ two translations = $240(n-5)!$ automorphisms. 

Answer (score 1):

There's a better easy lower bound of $2^{n/3-1}(n/3)!$ and minimum distance six: start with the parity code of all $n/3$-bit words with an even number of ones, and replace the bits of each code word with $000$ or $111$.

Answer (score 0):

For the additive group {0, 1}^n , it seems to me that every non-singular binary nxn matrix provides one F_2 linear bijective map from {0, 1}^n to itself .  As I recall, asymptotically the number of these bijective linear maps is at least C 2^(n^2), for some C>0 .  In other words, a strictly positive proportion of random nxn matrices over F_2 has non-zero determinant, and an nxn matrix over F_2 has nxn entries, each being 0 or 1.  When you say automorphism, are you referring to automorphisms of the additive group (F_2)^n ?  Thanks.
David Bernier

Comment: Thanks for your response. I'm referring to automorphisms of the hypercube [1], which are substantially more restricted than $F_2^n$. For instance the linear map [[1 1] [1 0]] is an automorphism of $F_2^2$ but not of the square. 

[1] http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Hyperoctahedral_group

Comment: I might be mistaken.  But perhaps the autmorphism group is the same as the hroups that preserve the Hamming distance on the metric space {0,1}^n with the Hamming distance metric?
Noam Elkies wrote a survey article on linear error-correcting codes that was published in the Notices of the AMS:
Elkies, Noam; "Lattices, Linear Codes, and Invariants, Part II",
  Notices of the AMS, Volume 47 number 11, December  2000.
http://www.ams.org/notices/200011/index.html